# Rock Paper Scissor Javascript only lets me tie, no matter what I input when invoking the function. I don't understand where I went wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

First off: I am sorry for another rock paper scissors JS question.

I do not think I made any errors with syntax and honestly do not comprehend why it always returns "tie" three times in a row, stating that the computer chose the same choice, three times in a row. If I re-run the code it chooses a different choice, but it still repeats three times, despite the user input in the function evocations being different in all three...

```js
const computer = Math.random()

function game(user, computer){
  if (user = "paper" && computer > .66) {
    return console.log("computer chose paper! it's a tie");
  }
  else if (user = "rock" && computer <= .33 && computer <= .66) {
    return console.log("computer chose rock! it's a tie");
  }
  else if (user="scissors" && computer >= .33) {
    return console.log("computer chose scissors! it's a tie");
  }
  /* you lose */
  else if (user = "paper" && computer >= .33) { /*comp scissor */
    return console.log("computer chose scissors! you lose!");
  }
  else if (user = "scissors" && computer <= .33 && computer <= .66) { /* comp rock */
    return console.log("computer chose rock! you lose!");
  }
  else if (user = "rock" && computer > .66) { /* comp paper */
    return console.log("computer chose paper! you lose!");
  }
  /* you win */
  else if (user = "scissors" && computer > .66) { /* comp paper*/
    return console.log("computer chose paper! you win!");
  }
  else if (user = "rock" && computer >= .33) { /* comp scissors */
    return console.log("computer chose scissors! you win!");
  }
  else if (user = "paper" &&  computer <= .33 && computer <= .66) { /*rock */
    return console.log("computer chose rock! you win!");
  }
}

game("paper", computer);
game("rock", computer);
game("scissors", computer);
```

I know that there are definitely more efficient and different ways of creating this game, but I still want to understand what is wrong with what I did here, and the logic behind it... Thanks in advance. Have a good day.

Comment: `user = "paper"` is _not_ comparison. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you so much! I was looking for something like this all morning. Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = "paper" && computer > .66
```

Here it means that you are, setting `user` to whatever `computer > .66` evaluates to.

---

You should use either [`Strict equal (===)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) or [`Equal (==)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

```js
const computer = Math.random();

function game(user, computer) {
  if (user === "paper" && computer > 0.66) {
    return console.log("computer chose paper! it's a tie");
  } else if (user === "rock" && computer <= 0.33 && computer <= 0.66) {
    return console.log("computer chose rock! it's a tie");
  } else if (user === "scissors" && computer >= 0.33) {
    return console.log("computer chose scissors! it's a tie");
  } else if (user === "paper" && computer >= 0.33) {
    /* you lose */
    /*comp scissor */
    return console.log("computer chose scissors! you lose!");
  } else if (user === "scissors" && computer <= 0.33 && computer <= 0.66) {
    /* comp rock */
    return console.log("computer chose rock! you lose!");
  } else if (user === "rock" && computer > 0.66) {
    /* comp paper */
    return console.log("computer chose paper! you lose!");
  } else if (user === "scissors" && computer > 0.66) {
    /* you win */
    /* comp paper*/
    return console.log("computer chose paper! you win!");
  } else if (user === "rock" && computer >= 0.33) {
    /* comp scissors */
    return console.log("computer chose scissors! you win!");
  } else if (user === "paper" && computer <= 0.33 && computer <= 0.66) {
    /*rock */
    return console.log("computer chose rock! you win!");
  }
}

game("paper", computer);
game("rock", computer);
game("scissors", computer);
```

---

BTW the code has become messy and long you should use the `switch` statement at the place of `if else`. Something like this:

---

**Some useful resources**

- [Strict equal (===) Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)
- [Equal (==) Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

Comment: Ah I understand perfectly now. Thank you!